# Need help to modify xml with python

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML string where I want to modify the model type for specific interface.

```
<domain type='kvm'>
   <devices>
     <interface type='network'>
       <mac address='52:54:00:a8:fe:3d'/>
       <source network='ovirtmgmt'/>
       <model type='virtio'/>
     </interface>
     <interface type='network'>
       <mac address='52:54:00:a8:fe:7d'/>
       <source network='nat'/>
       <model type='virtio'/>
     </interface>
     <interface type='network'>
       <mac address='52:80:00:a8:66:20'/>
       <source network='vm'/>
       <model type='virtio'/>
     </interface>
   </devices>
</domain>
```

Now, I want to change model `type='e1000'` where source `network='nat'`. How can I do that?

Comment: pretty sure you can find eveythin you need here `https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html`

Comment: [lxml](http://lxml.de/) is another favorite.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multiple `find*()` calls. You can do it in one call:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('input.xml')

for model in tree.findall(".//source[@network='nat']/../model"):
    model.set('type', 'e1000')

tree.write('output.xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some crude ElementTree code that does the job. In a real program you'd probably want some error checking. But if you're sure your XML data will always be perfect, and that every `interface` tag will always contain a `source` tag and a `model` tag, then this code will do the job.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET 

data = '''
<domain type='kvm'>
   <devices>
     <interface type='network'>
       <mac address='52:54:00:a8:fe:3d'/>
       <source network='ovirtmgmt'/>
       <model type='virtio'/>
     </interface>
     <interface type='network'>
       <mac address='52:54:00:a8:fe:7d'/>
       <source network='nat'/>
       <model type='virtio'/>
     </interface>
     <interface type='network'>
       <mac address='52:80:00:a8:66:20'/>
       <source network='vm'/>
       <model type='virtio'/>
     </interface>
   </devices>
</domain>
'''

tree = ET.fromstring(data)

for iface in tree.iterfind('devices/interface'):
    network = iface.find('source').attrib['network']
    if network == 'nat':
        model = iface.find('model')
        model.attrib['type'] = 'e1000'

ET.dump(tree)
```

**output**

```
<domain type="kvm">
   <devices>
     <interface type="network">
       <mac address="52:54:00:a8:fe:3d" />
       <source network="ovirtmgmt" />
       <model type="virtio" />
     </interface>
     <interface type="network">
       <mac address="52:54:00:a8:fe:7d" />
       <source network="nat" />
       <model type="e1000" />
     </interface>
     <interface type="network">
       <mac address="52:80:00:a8:66:20" />
       <source network="vm" />
       <model type="virtio" />
     </interface>
   </devices>
</domain>
```

If you're using an old version of Python you may not have `iterfind`. In which case, replace it with `findall`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, but this is also worked for me

```
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for interface in root.findall('devices/interface'):
    if interface.find('source/[@network="nat"]') != None:
      model = interface.find('model')
      model.set('type', 'e1000')

new_xml = ET.tostring(root)
```